# INSERT INTO number value with comma thousand delimiter

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

My SQL is

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Price) VALUE ('" & ItemString & "', " & PriceValue & ")"
```

It works fine.  But, if price is `12,345.67.`  SQL error message is

Number of Query Values and Destination Fields are not the same.

It is because the value thousand comma delimiter. How should I modify my `SQL` to let the number value has comma delimiter (and possible $ sign)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try within double quotes?

Comment: and what is the datatype of Price column?

Comment: Double quotes is for string data type. Price is single data type.  I use below and it works. "INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Price) VALUE ('" & ItemString & "', " & Format(PriceValue,"General  Number") & ")"

Answer (score 3):

This is where you always must use Str to convert your decimal number to a US-formatted string expression ignoring your local settings:

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Price) VALUE ('" & ItemString & "', " & Str(PriceValue) & ")"
```

The magic about Str is that is *always* inserts a dot as the decimal separator, nothing more, nothing less. This makes it bullet-proof and the simplest possible solution.

Most other methods will fail in international environments where the decimal separator is not a dot.

Comment: gr8 solution! I 've never noticed this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Recordset` instead of an `INSERT INTO` query:

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1 where 1=0")
RS.AddNew
RS("Item") = ItemString
RS("Price") = PriceValue
RS.Update
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
```

Notes:

- The `Recordset` automagically takes care of all the nasty gotchas like different decimal separators, quotes in strings, correct date/time values, and so on.
  So you don't need to mess around with strings, convert numbers etc.
- In order for this code to work, your Access database needs a reference to any version of the `Microsoft DAO Object Library`...this should already be the case in most newer Access versions
- The WHERE clause (`where 1=0`) is because the `Recordset` needs to "connect" to the table to know column names etc.
  But we are appending new rows only, so we don't actually need to load any existing rows, hence `where 1=0`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query assumes that your `Price` column has type `MONEY`:

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Price) VALUE ('" & ItemString & "', CAST(" & PriceValue & ") AS MONEY))"
```

I am casting the `PriceValue` parameter to type `MONEY`, which should work so long as it has the format `$XXX,XXX.XX`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no 'currency' data type in a mysql database, just store the value. Format it as a currency in the front-end. Similarly, you could process price to strip formatting before inserting into the table.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to append commas to the numeric or integer values in sql query.
Rather insert the values that supports the data type of the column and can be converted to the format required in UI.
For retrieval,you can use some thing like :

select testCol,replace(convert(varchar,cast(Price as money),1), '.00','') from testTbl.

Result :

testCol (No column name)
asd      12,346
asd     12,346

Answer (score 0):

I use below and it works.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Price) VALUE ('" & ItemString & "', " & Format(PriceValue,"General Number") & ")
```